# iOS:How to listen to the change of photos and albums changes

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

Is there any way to listen to the change of ipad's photos and albums? Something like `NSNotification`. I used to use "`ALAssetLibraryChangedNotification`" but i  found it not appropriate for listening photo changes.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? When your app comes to foreground, whatever is the state of the photo library, it is very unlikely to change during your app's execution as no other app can access and edit library contents in background. So why exactly do you want to listen to photo library changes? If you want to do this while your app is in background, its not possible, but i would say not required as you can always fetch the current state when your app becomes active..

Comment: thanks for your comment.So what if I start the UIImagePicker to take photos? or is there any simple way to check out whether the photos have increased or decreased when my app becomes active? thanks.

Comment: you can enumerate the assets https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722-CH1-SW57

Comment: e,is there any more simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this.

The best way to do it is to look at the assets in `appDidFinishLaunching` and then see the changes that you're interested in.

A few [apps on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/1-second-everyday/id587823548?mt=8) do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this in your appDelegate: `registerChangeObserver:`
The entire process is mentioned here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHPhotoLibrary/registerChangeObserver: